# submit with javascript inside a foreach php

Tags: javascript, ajax

Editing my question

I java a form with submit without refresh but this form is inside a foreach

where can I put javascript? inside the foreach or out?

if OUT how can I give a unic name

```js
  <script>
    const myForm = document.getElementById('follow<?php echo $card['user_id']; ?>');

    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(this);

        fetch('../config/follow.php', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }).then(function(response){
            return response.text();
        }).then(function(text){
            //alert(text);
                $("#atualizar").load(window.location.href + " #atualizar" );            
        }).catch(function(error){
            //alert(error);
            alert('Não foi possível concluir a operação');
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="follow<?php echo $card['user_id']; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="target" value="php $card['user_id'] ">


<div id="atualizar">
<!-- <button change after submit (0 or 1)-->
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I didn't understand what you want to describe. But I tried to debug the syntax of your code and i found that you need to add php keyword in the opening of the php tag `<form method="POST" id="follow<?php echo $card['user_id']; ?>">` and
`const myForm = document.getElementById('follow<?php echo $card['user_id']; ?>');`

Comment: not working too

Comment: nothing from javascript or ajax works 100%

Comment: Solved... the problem was that I put require_once, it was called only once.. put only REQUIRE worked